# Не стартует модуль Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, spring-cloud

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
}

group 'demo.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "2021.0.0")
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'registry.RegistryApp'
        )
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap"
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server"
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config"
    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.12"
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}
```

При запуске выдаёт **Error creating bean with name 'configurationPropertiesBeans' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/autoconfigure/ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration.class]**

Практически все Гугл-советы это добавить **implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap"**, но это уже сделано.

В случае с другим модулем с похожим билдом это помогло:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
}

group 'demo.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'config.ConfigApp'
        )
    }
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "2021.0.0")
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap"
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-server"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.6.3"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

а тут в чем дело не понимаю.

Трасса:

```
2022-02-18 17:52:18.810  WARN 7840 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurationPropertiesBeans' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/autoconfigure/ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeans] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1d16e93]
2022-02-18 17:52:19.610  INFO 7840 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-02-18 17:52:19.722 ERROR 7840 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurationPropertiesBeans' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/autoconfigure/ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeans] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1d16e93]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:567) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:414) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:164) [spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:212) [spring-cloud-context-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar:2.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:117) [spring-cloud-context-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar:2.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:74) [spring-cloud-context-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar:2.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176) [spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169) [spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) [spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131) [spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:85) [spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:66) [spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:120) [spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:114) [spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:65) [spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:296) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at registry.RegistryApp.main(RegistryApp.java:12) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeans] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1d16e93]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481) ~[spring-core-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:321) ~[spring-core-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:232) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:210) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:149) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:305) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463) ~[spring-core-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    ... 41 common frames omitted

2022-02-18 17:52:19.734 ERROR 7840 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurationPropertiesBeans' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/autoconfigure/ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeans] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1d16e93]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:567) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) [spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:414) [spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) [spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:164) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:212) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar:2.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:117) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar:2.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:74) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar:2.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:85) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:66) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:120) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:114) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:65) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:338) [spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:296) [spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) [spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) [spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at registry.RegistryApp.main(RegistryApp.java:12) [main/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeans] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1d16e93]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481) ~[spring-core-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:321) ~[spring-core-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:232) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:210) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:149) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:305) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463) ~[spring-core-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    ... 41 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

> Error creating bean with name 'configurationPropertiesBeans' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/autoconfigure/ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration.class]

Это не корневая причина. Корневая причина

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata
```

Т.е. не хватает СпрингБутовских классов, которые во втором случае неявно приходят вместе с `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.6.3`